# Source Safe, Exclusive Lock on Files

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe

My Hard Drive has failed with some Files in Visual Studio 2005 not checked-in, the changes are minor, however I am unable to edit these files on another machine as source safe says it is checked out by another user. Is there any work around to 'unlock' these files so I can continue with my projects? Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have VSS Admin rights, you can undo checkout via the Visual SourceSafe Client.

Comment: +1 Altough I believe that logging on to sourcesafe with the user who has the files checked out would be enough to "Undo Checkout".

Answer (score 1):

Is the other user you? I'm assuming the failed disk still has the files available...

**on a separate bit of disk** - i.e. don't overwrite the "good" files yet:

In VSS explorer, locate the files and undo checkout. It'll ask you to confirm; agree. Now check the files back out. Copy the **good** files over these, and check in.